# Spring boot + Envers ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to wire in Hibernate Envers into my Spring Boot app, and I get this exception:
I've tried a lot of different dependencies for Envers, because this seems like dependency conflict issue, but nothing helped. 
When I start the app, everything is ok, but when I try to annotate class with @Audited this exception drops.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean         with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.base.BaseApplication.main(BaseApplication.java:11) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator.integrate(EnversIntegrator.java:94) ~[hibernate-envers-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

My application.properties

```
        spring.profiles.active = dev


    spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
    spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

    # ===============================
    # = JPA / HIBERNATE
    # ===============================


    spring.jpa.show-sql = true
    logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace

    # Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
    # schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
    # the project
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

    # Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL5InnoDBSpatialDialect
    spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatial56Dialect
    spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database

    # Username and secret
    spring.datasource.username = root
    spring.datasource.password = root
    server.port=8082
```

Gradle build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.2.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

jar {
    baseName = 'Base'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:'1.4.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version:'1.4.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version:'1.4.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools', version: '1.3.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version:'5.1.40'
    compile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version:'0.7.5'
    compile group: 'com.vividsolutions', name: 'jts', version:'1.13'
    compile group: 'com.bedatadriven', name: 'jackson-datatype-jts', version:'2.3'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-spatial', version:'5.0.11.Final'
    compile group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version:'3.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-email', version: '1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-core', version: '8.5.6'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version:'2.4.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version:'2.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-envers'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version:'1.4.2.RELEASE'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.6'
}
```

Comment: Stop mixing versions. You are mixing Spring Boot 1.5, 1.4 and 1.3 and with that are also mixing hibernate versions also due to the inclusion of `hibernate-spatial` all the `org.hibernate` versions need to have the same versions your mixture of different versions is causing errors.

Comment: The Spring Boot plugin that you're using allows you to "omit version numbers when declaring dependencies that are managed in the BOM". Take a look at [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-dependency-management). That should help to avoid mixing versions and produce a more concise and maintainable build script.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved adding the `hibernate-core` dependency, this dependency has the missing class (*SharedSessionContractImplementor*), so you can add it to your gradle file.
I used the `hibernate-core 5.0.11.final` for `spring-boot 1.4.2.RELEASE`

**Gradle:**

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.0.11.Final'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution is to use `spring-data-envers` instead of the original `hibernate-envers`

`implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-envers'`